# There exists a nonzero element $x \in W$ such that $x \perp V$ if $\dim(W) > \dim(V)$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, inner-products

Consider an $n$-dimensional Euclidean space $U$. Let $V, W \subseteq U$ be two subspaces with dimensions $\dim(V) = k$ and $\dim(W) = k+1$ for some $k < n$.

How can we prove that there exists a nonzero element $x \in W$ such that $x \perp V$, i.e., the inner product $x^T y = 0$ for any $y \in V$?

If $V$ is a subspace of $W$, the above is obvious. But what if it is not? Since $W$ has a higher dimension, we know there must exist a nonzero element $x \in W$ that does not belong to $V$. But I failed to go any further...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have $\dim (V^{\perp} + W) = \dim V^{\perp}+\dim W - \dim (V^{\perp}\cap W) $.

Then $\dim V^{\perp}=n-k$, $\dim W=k+1$, and $\dim (V^{\perp}+W) \leq n$.

Thus, $\dim (V^{\perp} \cap W) \geq 1$.

Comment: It's an elegant way to show existence! Following your earlier comments, do you think we are able to use the Gram Schmidt process to construct such a vector $x$? I am curious about it.

Comment: Now, I am giving a second thought to my earlier comment, I think it is unnecessary to start with $V\cap W$. Directly find basis of $V^{\perp}$ from Gram Schmidt, also basis of $W$. Then solve the linear system, span of basis of $V^{\perp}$ = span of basis of $W$.

Comment: I see. Very nice! Have learned a lot from you!

Comment: @Stupid_Guy Thank you. I wonder if you can see my editing history. My pre-editing answer is blatantly wrong. I learned from this problem that some things can go wrong very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Write

$$V+W = V_1 \oplus (V \cap W ) \oplus W_1$$

where $V = V_1 \oplus (V \cap W) $ and $V_1 \perp (V \cap W)$ and similar equalities for $W_1$. With finally also $V_1 \perp W_1$. For this, we can take for $V_1$ the orthogonal complement of $V \cap W $ in $V$. And for $W_1$ the orthogonal complement of $V_1 \oplus (V \cap W)$ in $V +W$.

Based on the given dimensions for $V,W$, we have $\dim W_1 \ge 1$ and any non zero element $x \in W_1$ satisfies the desired result.

Comment: I am considering when $V \cap W = \varnothing$, then basically $V_1 = V$ and $W_1  =W$. But it is not necessary that $V \perp W$?

Comment: You will have indeed $V_1=V$, but not $W_1 =W$. You will chose $W_1$ to be an orthogonal complement of $V_1$ in $V+W$ in that case.

Comment: This is great. Start Gram Schmidt process in $V\cap W$ first, then orthogonalize basis of $V$, then the remaining basis vectors of $V+W$ gives this decompostion.

Comment: Thank you! I need more time to understand it. I am considering a concrete example here. Consider $U = \mathbb{R}^3$ as the Euclidean space. Let $W = \{(x,y,0): x, y \in \mathbb{R}\}$, i.e., the first two dimensions. Let $V = \{(x,0,x): x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ to have only one dimension. We have $V+W = U$,  $V \cap W = \varnothing$ and $V_1 = V$. I wonder what should $W_1$ be here?

Comment: @Stupid_Guy I added a sentence to precise the construction of $V_1,W_1$.

Comment: @Stupid_Guy In the case of your example, $W_1$ will be an orthogonal complement of $V$ in $\mathbb R^3$. I.e. the linear subspace spanned by the vectors $(0,1,0),(1,0,-1)$.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Can we make sure that anything in $W_1$ is also in $W$?

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Thank you! I almost understand. I echo Sungjin's concern. Here essentially $W_1 = V^{\perp}$, and one more step to is to show $W \cap V^{\perp} \neq \varnothing$.